# Formula auto fills date column works on sheet but not in the form

Tags: excel, date, autofill

I'm using the formula to auto fill the date as soon as something is entered in the next column.

```
=If(B9="","",IF(A9="",NOW(),B9))
```

After doing this I applied the formula on the cells until row 48. Now anything when entered in source (screenshot for ref) the date is filled automatically. Works like a charm, all good.

Designed a userform for entering the data minus the date because using the above formula. Should work but it doesn't. Date comes as `1/1/1900`. Slightly off by a century +18 years, no big deal lol.

The code you can see in the screenshots which I've used for data entry. Originally I made the sheet up to 48 rows. Since when using userform the data is entering "only" after row 48 the table keeps expanding on and on and on. I've deleted the rows after 48 so many times that it's not even funny anymore.

Now the VBA code is off somehow or incomplete which makes this whole thing go funny. How can I fix this?

P.S. Using Excel 2016

Code for Add data button on the form. For this, the data is not starting to populate from row 9 column B. It starts after row 48.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dcc As Long
Dim abc As Worksheet

Set abc = Worksheets("January2019")
dcc = Sheets("January2019").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With abc

.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value


End With
```

Code for date.

```
=If(B9="","",IF(A9="",NOW(),B9))
```

The date auto works if enter data manually but when use the user form the date enters as 1/1/1900 and mentioned above the entry is made after row 48.

What I'm hoping/aiming for with this code and user form is:

In user form there is no option for date. I added the date formula in row 9 and then dragged it to row 48. Made the user form minus the date field because as soon as data is entered, date will get auto filled. And, the data starts filling in from the first available row which is B9. So now I'm lost because I do not know where the fault is or what goes off which makes this add at random rows and with date which is way off.

Comment: @BigBen I hope I've formatted the code correctly? Have a look and hope to have this resolved. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is there data in row 47? If so, that's why you are starting at row 48 with your `.Cells(dcc + 1, x)` regardless if row 9 is blank or not. `.End(xlUp).Row` is starting from the very bottom of the worksheet, and going straight up until it finds the **first non-empty cell from the *bottom***.

Comment: There is no data in row 47. In fact there is no data is anywhere. All the random data entered I selected and deleted. All columns + rows are empty.

Comment: OK I just quickly deleted all rows just to be 100% but still the same! I think this is not going to work. Sigh. Is there any easy code for the date to be entered by user form perhaps? I'm thinking if this doesn't work then I'll just add a title on user form saying date and a text box in which the date is auto filled and at the time of pressing add data the date also gets added in the sheet. Any thoughts on this idea?

Comment: What's the criteria for the date? And what column does it go in? I see the formula, but it doesn't say where the formula is located.

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking about the date formula. The date formula I entered "manually" in sheet in A9 which is the first empty row and is column A, Date. I dragged it till row 48 so it applies to all the rows. I just had this thought as well and deleted formatted table rows and all. No formula anywhere now and still doesn't work! Tried and still starts from row 10! Unbelievable....

Comment: There is no criteria tbh. Simple user form with same fields and boxes as sheet, minus the date. I didn't formatted the form properly so all the textboxes are named default names. I did something just now, copied the sheet and made a new one. Didn't applied the date formula in the sheet and used the userform to enter data. whola! it started entering from B9, which is named as source, A9 is date which is empty. So the last row formula working now and because I have no date details in user form there is no date entering in the sheet lol. If anybody have a vba code for date in user form?

Comment: Okay - so where exactly do you get this date from? Is it just today's date? Is it based on one of the `.TextBox#`?

Comment: The date is today's date. Date formula is not in VBA it's in sheet. I hope I'm making sense because you sure do but I'm thick... do apologies for not grasping the question fully.  In the code I have pasted in my post above, there is no mention of date in any of the textbox numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your formula and just use your current userform to add today's date.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim dcc As Long
    Dim abc As Worksheet

    Set abc = Worksheets("January2019")
    dcc = Sheets("January2019").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With abc

        .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

    End With
```

You do not need to add a space in your userform for the date to be entered.

> *...how to connect the drop down list from user form so that when month of february2019 is selected the sheet which is named february2019 gets the data...*

This should work:

```vb
Dim abc As Worksheet

Set abc = Worksheets(me.ComboBox1.Value)
```

Comment: @K.Davis. I'm gobsmacked, honestly. Here's what happened. I copied and pasted your code and it worked like a charm! I just added the clear boxes so the data entered is cleared. Many thanks, I mean like a ton of thanks for being patience with my out of this world explanations lol. Good man, you. By any change you don't know how to connect the drop down list from user form so that when month of february2019 is selected the sheet which is named february2019 gets the data rather then january2019. Same workbook just 12 sheets for each month to keep it tidy. Shall I post another question about this?

Comment: OK where do I add this code? Sorry for the most silly question. I tried it already but it gave error.    Set abc = Worksheets(me.ComboBox1.Value)    This line is highlighted and under the above code is,    dcc = Sheets("January2019").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    But if I delete this then row count will mess up again I think?

Comment: Try adding a `MsgBox me.ComboBox1.Value` (I am not sure if you are using a combobox or not - it needs to be whatever your 'dropdown' box you are talking about) and see if it provides the right outcome

Comment: I think updated 2 lines of code is meant to go in combobox1 (change) and there it's meant to be entered, right?

Comment: It's a ComboBox1 I checked, a drop down list open on the user form.

Comment: No you do not need to add a combobox_change() event. You need to get the combobox's value when you press the `CommandButton1`

Comment: That also didn't worked. It's giving red error and highlights the "me," in the error.

Comment: Is it a combobox? When you type `Me.` does it list `ComboBox1` as an option to choose from in the IntelliSense?

Comment: Yes the auto fill or IntelliSense comes up and yes I double checked it is a combobox.

Comment: Runtime error 9. script out of range. That's the error its giving. I selected february2019 from the combobox and entered dummy data but got that error.

Comment: I can’t recall if setting a worksheet obj is case sensitive or not. Make sure that all capitalization matches in your combo box with the worksheet name - just make sure it matches exactly the name of the ws. But you may need to post a new question on this showing exactly how you have your combobox set up so we have all the details.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm positive that code will work and it's me who's messing it about by entering it in the wrong manner. I will start a new question now. Cheers for your help!

Comment: I have posted the question. When you have a min to spare have a look at it just to see if I'm doing it right. Many thanks for your help. Cheers.